# Backbone differentiate client side rendering from server side rendering

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, single-page-application

I want to allow users to request webpages of my website both directly from the server or using links, which will be handled by Backbone's router.

When a user requests a webpage directly from the server, a full page is served (with html, head, body, stylesheets and scripts).

On the other hand when a user requests a webpage by clicking on a link, only the relevant part of the page is requested and then inserted in the correct place, and other elements of the webpage remain untouched.

By *inserting in the correct place* I mean creating a View once a particular route is reached. The view is then initialized and calls its render method to fetch the relevant part of the webpage and inserts it into DOM using `$el.html(content)`.

But I do not want to call the view's render method when a webpage was fetched directly from the server, because all needed content has already been rendered, and re-rendering it only causes some ui-flickering effects.

Is there some common way to let Views know that they shouldn't render themselves, because the fully rendered webpage has been fetched from the server?

I could pass a flag like `clientSideNavigation = true` to the router, everytime a link is clicked, which then will be passed to views by the router so that they know whether to render the content or not.

But it does not work when user uses aa back/foward buttons.

I could also check in a view if within its `$el` there is some particular element that should be present on this webpage - for instance if I had a view called `CatsView` I could check if `#cats-box` is within its `$el` element. But it involves some more DOM manipulations, which I would prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Have a root view and have place holder for child views. First time render the complete page from the server.

For rendering parts of the view on link clicks, you can define corresponding events hash on the root view.

Let the event handler callbacks call a controller(custom js object) which does the job of loading the data ,constructing the view and passing the data to it.

**Finally also update the url with Router navigate(http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) method with {trigger:false} to the corresponding url, so then when refresh is hit, the user comes back to the same view**.

In the router callback for the specified url call the same method on controller object by passing a flag so that the functionality is in sync and also using the flag you can prevent calling router navigate method since its not required.